# How to manage CSS performance in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, less-css

I have a performance question about css and themes in Mangeto 2.

Is is better for performance write the specific css for some page like homepage in a separated file, and only load that file in homepage?

or it is the same if i put all the css in one place like magento base came.

Comment: Try to use fewer CSS files. because every file sends a request to the server and takes some seconds. not for the CSS file but for all files.

Comment: Modern browsers will cache CSS files, so creating one for every page will result in more requests (one per page) rather than as few as one request for multiple pages. Also, a theme should probably include a lot of directives that are used site-wide. That means that a per-page CSS approach would require a lot of inefficient duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes css separate file is useful when we want our site page Optimization improve. it's gives a fast speed up to load page.

One css file which have common class which are used in every page and other files css for specific page.

So it's best way separate css for particular page because unused css are also load when page load. So Remove this unused css.

Do Same for JavaScript also.

[Click here to check unused css](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/coverage)

Answer (score 0):

Yes its better idea for speed optimize and only load the required css file particular page

and you can do this by creating separate css files for particular page like home page create new css custom-home.css and only call this css and remove all other css using layout xml

in cms_index_index.xml

```
 <head>
        <remove src="css/styles-m.css" />
        <remove src="all-other.css"/>
        <css src="css/custom-home.css"  />
    </head>
```

do same for other page like for category page use 
**catalog_category_view.xml** and for product page use **catalog_product_view.xml**

Hope this will help you.